# Able to list folders, but unable to list files using PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

Im tyring to display files in my folder directory. I am able to view the folder but not the files inside that folder.

Can you please identify where I went wrong?

```
<?php

             $username=$_SESSION['username' ];
              if(isset($_GET['directory'])){
                  if(strcmp($_GET['directory'],' userFolders/')==0){
                        $dir='userFolders/'.$username. '/';
                  }else{
                         $dir=$_GET['directory'];
                  }

                $myfolders=myfolders($dir);
                if(empty($myfolders)){
                    echo '<tr><td> <b> Your folder is empty </b></td><td></td><td></td></ tr>';
                }else{
                    foreach($myfolders as $folder){
                                     echo '<tr>
                                                <td align="left"><a target=_blank href="honey.php?directory=',$ folder,'"> ',$folder,'</a></td>
                                                <td align="center"> --- </td>
                                                <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
                                          </tr>';
                    }
                        $dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $dir");
                        while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {

                                if($file == "." || $file == "..")
                                continue;

                                     echo '<tr>
                                                <td align="left"><a target="_blank" href="'.$file.'"> ',$file,'</a></td>
                                                <td align="center"> --- </td>
                                                <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
                                          </tr>';
                        }
                        closedir($dir_handle);
                }
              }
          }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you try? Does it do nothing? Generate an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `myfolders()` isn't defined and the statement in Line 17 has syntax errors. You probably want [`scandir()`](http://php.net/scandir) for this.

I'd write it as **(tested)**:

```
<?php
$username=$_SESSION['username' ];

if(isset($_GET['directory']))
{
    if(strcmp($_GET['directory'],' userFolders/')==0)
    {
    $dir='userFolders/'.$username. '/';
    }

else
{
$dir=$_GET['directory'];
}

$myfolders=scandir($dir);

if(empty($myfolders))
{
echo '<tr><td> <b> Your folder is empty </b></td><td></td><td></td></ tr>';
}
else
{
    foreach($myfolders as $folder)
    {
    echo '<tr>
    <td align="left"><a target=_blank href="honey.php?directory=$folder"> $folder</a></td>
    <td align="center"> --- </td>
    <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
    </tr>';
    }

    $dir_handle = @opendir($dir) or die("Unable to open $dir");

    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) 
    {
    if($file == "." || $file == "..")
    continue;
    echo '<tr>
    <td align="left"><a target="_blank" href="'.$file.'"> ',$file,'</a></td>
    <td align="center"> --- </td>
    <td align="center"> <input type="image" src="delete.png" width="25" height="25"/></td>
    </tr>';
    }
    closedir($dir_handle);
}
```

}

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, and it opens a new browser but get a error 404 object not found!. I have a jpg image inside the folders. how do i view the images in the folder for my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space here: `$ folder` and a extra } at the end. It should be: `$folder`. Try changing this and let me know if it helped.